# _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function fetchTokensWithIndex at>

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, uniswap

I got this error `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function fetchTokensWithIndex at 0x7f217c9b1a20>: it's not the same object as scripts.getAllTokensList.fetchTokensWithIndex`. I know this is one of the most repetitive question but to be honest I'm not able understand the root cause of this issue. I have tried `multiprocessing`, `pathos.multiprocessing`, `concurrent.futures` all of them are giving the same issue. When I'm running the `multiprocessing` part from the global it's working but I'm facing the issue when I'm trying to run it from another function. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` is working fine so I guess my code is working as intended. Here is the piece of code.

```py
import csv
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed, ProcessPoolExecutor
from re import findall
from typing import Dict, Optional

from ape_ethereum import multicall
from loguru import logger

from scripts.Classes import Token
from scripts.colours import *
from scripts.contracts import *
from scripts.utils import *

def fetchTokensWithIndex(uniswap_v1_factory, start_id: int, end_id: int) -> list:
    call = multicall.Call()
    # print(f"Proceesing {end_id + 1 - start_id} number of tokens")
    for i in range(start_id, end_id + 1):
        call.add(uniswap_v1_factory.getTokenWithId, i)
    return list(call())

def batchGetUniswapAllTokens():
    [...]
    chunk_size = 200
    multicall_results = []
    num_threads = 5

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as executor:
        for start_id in range(1, token_count + 1, chunk_size):
            end_id = min(start_id + chunk_size - 1, token_count)
            futures = executor.submit(
                fetchTokensWithIndex, uniswap_v1_factory, start_id, end_id
            )
            multicall_results.append(futures)

    final_results = []
    for future in as_completed(multicall_results):
        final_results.extend(future.result())

def main():
    batchGetUniswapAllTokens()
```

I'm using the [ape](https://github.com/ApeWorX/ape) framework. Ape starts executing from the main function of any python script.

```bash
ape run scripts/getAllTokensList.py
```

**Update**

- Message from the devs:

```
It might not be multiprocessing friendly, we haven't tested for that
As an aside, using asynchronous processing is often a better 
solution for speeding up ape scripts because they involve a lot of network I/O
```

Comment: How are you running your code? What are the top-level packages/modules in your project? I'm guessing the issue is that there's a mismatch between how your modules are imported and how you're trying to run your "scripts", so you're getting two different `fetchTokensWithIndex` functions when pickle tries to import it as a self test prior to pickling

Comment: It looks like this script is imported twice with different names. You could put `print("NAME", __name__)` at the top of the script to see. I don't know how ape works, so am not sure how its happening. But if its a top level script (name is `"__main__"`) but also in the package tree, this would happen.

Comment: Try moving this file outside of the `script` directory tree.

Comment: @tdelaney printed the `__name__` & got this `NAME scripts.getAllTokensList`  twice. got the same when printed from the `main` & `batchGetUniswapAllTokens` fn. as well. What does this mean ?

Comment: @SaikatKarmakar - That's left me guessing. You should get `scripts.getAllTokensList` once because python shouldn't be importing and executing the same module twice, or 2 different names with one of them being `__main__`. Maybe ape is loading things in an odd way.

Comment: https://github.com/ApeWorX/ape/blob/main/src/ape_run/_cli.py this is the entry point I guess